# Fail configuration of MySQL server installation

Tags: mysql

I was trying to reinstall MySQLServer on my local machine (Win7 32), using Windows (x86, 32-bit), MSI Installer.

When wizard configure server, after installation, gives the error "Configuration failed", with details:

```
mysql-server-5.5-win32:6 - Looking for valid template
mysql-server-5.5-win32:13 - Found valid template.
mysql-server-5.5-win32:20 - Attempting to process template.
mysql-server-5.5-win32:26 - Processed template.
mysql-server-5.5-win32:33 - Attempting to configure service.
mysql-server-5.5-win32:40 - Configured service.
mysql-server-5.5-win32:46 - Attempting to start service.
mysql-server-5.5-win32:100 - Unable to configure service.
mysql-server-5.5-win32:100 - Product configuration controller finished configuration.
```

Why does it happen?

Can it result from using a wrong "old" password that I put in the installation wizard, to set a new password? If yes - How can I clean up ALL previous settings of MySQL server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uninstall MySql and all his components excepted Oracle installer, re launch installer, do normally, when your error comes, finish the procedure of installation.

Next step, in start menu search "services", execute services administration tool, right click on the service "MySql Server XX", select "Connexion" tab and check "system account" on start user, launch the process and it would work.

Comment: wow, they should fix this because if u check the tcp/ip box it just works right away..

Answer (score 3):

[image]

I was struggling with upper problem over 3 days and I think there is a bug when you want to install this with local connection (not tick TCP connection) via .msi installer. After i selected this the configuration passed properly with no fail configuration. My sollution was to run this with set tick on TCP connection and then in server folder in `my.ini` file just uncomment line `# skip-networking` .

Other tips:

- Turn off the firewall or add rule for installer to accept public/private net connections.
- Under admin privileages use `netstat -ab | more` command to check ports usage
- If u fail with earlier installations run `services.msc` command find your service (installer set is as defauls something like MySQL56,MySQL56_1 - depending on version) get the name of this service and under admin privileage run cmd and type `sc stop "coppiedServiceName"` if the service is running and later `sc delete "coppiedServiceName"`
- In some forum says that if might be usefull to turn of windows defender or antivirus too
- If you change default installation directory after reinstall check for old install files on C:\Program Files C:\ProgramData and get rid of them

Hope somebody find this usefull.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on Windows XP. The problem was caused by the localization. I had to change the path to the All User's AppData folder using regedit. The original path contained a non ANSI character.

The registry key is this:
"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders"

The value name is this:"Common AppData"

The original value was: "%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Data aplikací"

I changed it to: "%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\AppData"

Then the installer succeeded.

NOTE: Uninstall MySQL first, then change the path, then install MySQL again.