# MySQL server configuration failed

Tags: mysql, installation

I'm trying to install the latest version of MySQL community server on my computer, got the following error:

```
mysql-server-5.5-win32:6 - Looking for valid template
mysql-server-5.5-win32:12 - Found valid template.
mysql-server-5.5-win32:18 - Attempting to process template.
mysql-server-5.5-win32:25 - Processed template.
mysql-server-5.5-win32:31 - Attempting to configure service.
mysql-server-5.5-win32:37 - Configured service.
mysql-server-5.5-win32:43 - Attempting to start service.
mysql-server-5.5-win32:100 - Unable to configure service.
mysql-server-5.5-win32:100 - Product configuration controller finished configuration.
```

I tried to un-re-install and changed the pathway for data and installation, no difference. 
Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fail configuration of MySQL server installation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10822267/fail-configuration-of-mysql-server-installation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few different things that could be wrong, but here's a really good step by step guide to make sure you aren't missing something small.

http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/how-do-i/install-mysql-windows-7.php

good luck, and I'm sure it's something small.